# Easiest way to generate APK in Android Studio

Tags: libgdx, apk

What is the easiest way to generate APK files in Android Studio?

My project's `android/build/outputs` folder contains two apk files: `android-debug`, `android-debug-unaligned`. Should I use these? Which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) article
Scroll down to the android studio section.

By default, the file should be located in your //android directory
the default name for your apk is android-release.apk

Comment: Yes, but I use it with libGDX.

Comment: So android-debug, android-debug-unaligned are not runnable?

Comment: Usually android-debug.apk can be installed and run on development device, android-debug-unaligned.apk is an intermediate output of the debug build that is used by the IDE to speed up debbuging tools and is probably not runnable on device (as far as i know).
android-debug.apk is not (should not be) publishable on a store. So if you want to distribute your app on a store, you'll need to generate a signed android-release.apk file. Read the article linked by Fish, and follow the instructions if you want to generate a release version.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate APK in Android Studio as:

- Open your project in Android Studio
- Open the menu Build then click on "generate signed apk" (then a pop-up displays)
- Select apk
- Then enter key store path and its password (assuming you have already one)
- Click the check boxes -> finish.

After the gradle build the APK gets generated.