# How to generate an APK from Java project?

Tags: java, android, apk

I want to write some Java code with `Appium`.

How can I generate an APK from my Java project?

I'm working on `IntelliJ`\ `Android Studio`.

Should I just open a dummy?

I need an APK (test app) in order to run this automatically over another APK app (tested app).

Comment: By default you don't need to generate it... http://stackoverflow.com/a/16683625/3850595

Comment: Why you want to have source code when .apk file should be sufficient to run the automation script? You just need to have desired capabilities of the app and device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to generate APK in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797803/easiest-way-to-generate-apk-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are working with "LibGDX" or other libaries?! It´s a long time ago but as far as i remember i didnt know either and so I searched in the "workspace"-directory (used Eclipse and that was the directory where all my files were saved) for something with ".apk" 
I think that work only because I used the Android Emutator (I not recommend it because it is very slow). So everytime I ran the Project on the Emulator somewhere in my directory an ".apk" was created. So i could move it on my phone and tried it there.
I know this is not the perfect solution, because if you want to upload it to the Playstore this way doesnt work, because you have to sign it in somewhere (I am not sure how this works, so please correct me if I am wrong). 
If you want to do it that way i would try it like it is already said:

"https://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html

I think this link very use full for you."(aravinthkumar j)